# using Add-Type in multiple scripts

Tags: powershell, smo

I have a code to import  a dll to my scripts. But i'm copying this part of code in every script where I'm using this dll. I think this is not a good practice. What would be a good practice here to avoid code replication.

Example of what i'm doing:

```
function Backup-Database
{
    $pathSMO = "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\SDK\Assemblies\Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll"
    $pathSMOEx = "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\SDK\Assemblies\Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended.dll"
    #imports
    Add-Type -path $pathSMO
    Add-Type -path $pathSMOEx

    #other stuff...
}

function Restore-Database
{
    $pathSMO = "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\SDK\Assemblies\Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll"
    $pathSMOEx = "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\SDK\Assemblies\Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended.dll"
    #imports
    Add-Type -path $pathSMO
    Add-Type -path $pathSMOEx

    #other stuff...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forgive me if i'm off base but you should just be able to move the type declaration above the functions and still have it accessible within the functions. Bastardizing example 1 from the [TechNet for Add-Type](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849914.aspx)

```
$source = @"
public class BasicTest
{
  public static int Add(int a, int b)
    {
        return (a + b);
    }
  public int Multiply(int a, int b)
    {
    return (a * b);
    }
}
"@

Add-Type -TypeDefinition $source

function test1{
    [BasicTest]::Add(4, 3)
}

Function test2{
    $basicTestObject = New-Object BasicTest
    $basicTestObject.Multiply(5, 2)
}

test1

test2
```

**Output from code above**

```
7
10
```

As you can see the definition is outside the functions. Hopefully using the quote in proper context if the `-NameSpace` parameter is omitted then *the type is generated in the global namespace.*